# Ace Editor. Adding explanation tab in autocomplete

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I have my own custom functions in the autocomplete and I want to add a tab next to autocomplete to show what the function does each time a user selects the function.

Something like this in the VScode:

[image]

I found a similar example shown in this [link](https://github.com/securingsincity/react-ace/issues/338) but in a snippet.

How can I achieve this in ace?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add getDocTooltip method to completer similar to https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/7285dad33867771a688a96bbf2309f4e995a5b7d/lib/ace/ext/language_tools.js#L82 or add docHTML property to the items https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/autocomplete.js#L362